# Variable 'std::ifstream infile' has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Вот такая вот ошибка

> variable 'std::ifstream infile' has initializer but incomplete type

Вот сам код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char buff[80];
    vector<string> s;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("rhume.txt");

    while(1)
    {
        infile.getline(buff, sizeof(buff));
        if(infile.eof()) break;
        s.push_back(buff);
    }

    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    for(int i=0; i < s.size(); i++)
        cout << s[i] << endl;
    infile.close();

    cout << endl << endl;
    cout << accumulate(s.begin(), s.end(), static_cast<string>(""))
    << endl;

}
```

подскажите что не так я сделал?Точнее переписал с книжки по с++)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В список инклудов нужно добавить одну строку

```
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream
```

Comment: он не входит в iostream?

Comment: нет конечно же. iostream это всякий консольный ввод-вывод (`cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, `clog`).

Comment: спасибо!Буду знать)